# Java swing how to do when mouse over pop out a small box to show details

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, mouseover

I have a JTable displays the event accordingly, I want to do like when mouse over the table cell will pop out a small box show the event details. Something like tooltip how can i do that? is there any component in swing doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a read about [How to Use Tables: Specifying Tool Tips for Cells](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#celltooltip).

Answer (score 1):

Use JToolTip and HTML. More info here:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html